# Block access to website based on Country with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security

I want to deny access to my Wordpress site, mainly for the following country:

- India

Comment: A simple Google search would have pointed you in the right direction. Anyways, there you go, [Block access to website based on Country with .htaccess](https://www.google.com/search?q=Block+access+to+website+based+on+Country+with+.htaccess&oq=Block+access+to+website+based+on+Country+with+.htaccess&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.363j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: It's great to see you've put in the leg work by proving us with.... oh, wait.

Comment: I googled it but didn't understand how you would add the ip list into the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

you can use build in plugin for that i have do it many time with this plugin

```
 https://wordpress.org/plugins/iq-block-country/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list for IPv4 - 
[in-block.txt](https://iotaku.ir/in-block.txt)

but It's better to use cloudflare to block countries

Comment: Is there a specific way I need to add it into the .htaccess file?

Comment: nope, just  edit  htaccess ( use something like notepad ) and paste all of it. but again I'm saying this way is **not recommended**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [geoip_country_code_by_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-country-code-by-name.php) to determine country code. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` gives you the IP address, therefore

```
geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

gives you the country code of the user. Check this country code and if it is invalid, send an error page as response:

```
function isValidCountry() {
    $invalidCountries = array("IN");
    return !in_array(geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), $invalidCountries);
}

if (isValidCountry()) {
    //Do normal stuff
} else {
    //Restrict
}
```